# How to get the class of a certain trait's val instance?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, traits

Sorry if my question is dumb, but I am a Scala beginner. I have something similar to the following:

```
trait Pet {
  val name: String
}

class Cat(val name: String) extends Pet
class Dog(val name: String) extends Pet

def eval(animal: Pet): returnType = {
  ...
}
```

I am trying to manipulate the animal differently if it's a Cat than if it was a Dog.
Here's what I've tried so far:

```
def eval(animal: Pet): returnType = {
  if (animal.type == Cat) {
    print("This is cat")
  }
  else {
    print("This is dog")
  }
}
```

But, this does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `x.type` is a singleton type, that's not what you need

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, don't use `val` in a `trait` unless you know exactly how initialisation of class trees works.

The actual problem can be solved using a `case class` and `match`:

```
trait Pet {
  def name: String
}

case class Cat(name: String) extends Pet
case class Dog(name: String) extends Pet

def eval(animal: Pet) =
  animal match {
    case Cat(name) =>
      print("This is cat")
    case Dog(name) =>
      print("This is dog")
  }
```